# What it means to get !locks - all threads have 'lock count' = 0

Tags: windbg

I opened crashdump with WinDbg and when I use `!locks` command, I get 3 threads output and each one has "lock count" = 0.

Which means those threads not lock any object (from what I understand).
How can I proceed from this point investigate the root cause for issue I'm handling? (failure in performance system)

The code I'm debugging contains managed and unmanaged code.

Comment: Google "code profiling"

Comment: What issue are you trying to debug? A hang? Locks aren't the only cause of an application hang.

Answer (score 2):

A Lock Count of 0 on a thread means that nobody is synchronizing on the thread. It does not mean that the thread has not locked any objects. If you lock an object, that information is stored on that object (e.g. a Critical Section, Mutex or Semaphore).

On one hand side you're looking for locks, which lets me assume that a deadlock occured. On the otherhand side you mention performance. It should be quite easy to distinguish these two. With a deadlock, you'll not get results any more, sometimes CPU usage even drops to 0% for the process. With a performance issue, wou will still get results, but you'll need to wait longer.

A crash dump file can help solving deadlock issues, but it will rarely help solving performance issues, especially if you only have one crash dump file.

You should use a performance profiler to analyze performance issues.